Movie similar to "If Only"
I vaguely remember the movie, but the story line was same as "If Only 2004". There were minor differences to the story though. 
A guy loves her wife/girlfriend but because of priorities of work is unable to give 100 to his love. His wife/girlfriend dies. He is given a second chance and same story repeats that he thinks was a dream. Only this time he appreciates the time together more. 
There is a difference to the scene that I remember from this movie. 
On "If Only" : When the person gets the second chance, he  wakes up next to his girlfriend totally surprised and freaks out after hearing and seeing his girlfriend alive.
On The other movie : When the person gets the second chance, he is seen sitting next to his wife/girlfriend watching her sleep. The lady wakes up little later.
I would really appreciate if anyone can help on this.
Language: English
Year: I should be 2000 +-5 years.
Saw it on Star Movies.

The only film I can think of right now that has a similar plot is Three Days from 2001, but I'm not sure about the part with him waking up next to her (I think she just walks in the door and he's shocked to see her).

This looks very similar. I will google up some more clips. Thanks @Walt

yes it is the movie. Please post it as an answer.

OK, no problem. Glad you found it.

This is Three Days from 2001 starring Kristin Davis, Reed Diamond and Tim Meadows.

Ten years ago, Andrew married his childhood sweetheart, Beth. Now Andrew's a high-powered literary agent, but his relationship with his wife has not fared as well. When Beth is tragically killed just days before Christmas, an angel gives Andrew the chance to relive the last three days his wife was alive. But he can't change fate and Beth will still lose her life. However, Andrew can still discover the gift Beth needs most from him.

When he sees her alive again, he figures her death was a dream. Here's a (rather low-quality) trailer:



